# SOAP over WebSockets in Apache CXF?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websocket, cxf

Does CXF support WebSockets as a transport protocol?

I need to support multiplexed SOAP and WebSocket protocol looks perfect as a starting point. It is a bidirectional and full duplex protocol.
By multiplexing I mean that the client can send messages without waiting for the response, and the responses may be sent back in the different order that they were sent (I will use message / conversation ID, to identify the request and response)

It should be very similar to JMS where CXF can receive requests and send responses asynchronously and in any order e.g.:
[image]

I looked for the information in the mailing list history, but it's still not clear for me if CXF supports [WebSocket out-of-the box](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/websocket.html) or I need to implement my own [transport](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/custom-transport.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The question I asked is still valid, but there is one answer that satisfies me :)

Instead of `java.util.concurrent` queues I can simply use JMS. Then, depending on the context and scalability requirements I can use in-jvm queue or distributed queues. In such case CXF is already supporting [SOAP over JMS](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/soap-over-jms-10-support.html).

What needs to be ensured is to have a queue per WebSocket connection (or one can use [JMS Message Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncer/index.html)). It's because the response to the request that was received by WebSocket A MUST be sent back with the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Hi a bit late answer I guess, but it seems as Soap over Websocket is supported in CXF. The main problem configuring it is getting the correct netty dependencies in place which is not properly described on CXF web site. The list of dependencies that worked for me is described in the following post:

[SOAP over Websocket with Appache CXF and Embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562706/soap-over-websocket-with-appache-cxf-and-embedded-jetty)

The post contains a working example of CXF soap endpoint using websocket transport.

I will summarize the nessesary dependencies that will make it work:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.asynchttpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.39</version>
             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.56.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```